# jQuery .map() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basically no experience with jQuery, just enough to get by *most* of the time. However, I recently have been changing some templates around and came across a piece of jQuery that I didn't write, but is throwing an error (`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /`). I'm not really sure where to start. All I know so far is that I'm fairly certain this piece of code is causing it, and it's choking right at the `scrollItems` line:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $(".nav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 50,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
            return item;
        }

        ///////////////FANCYBOX 
        $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
            arrows: true,
            padding: 0,
            closeBtn: true,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            closeEffect: 'fade',
            prevEffect: 'fade',
            nextEffect: 'fade',
            helpers: {
                media: {},
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                },
                buttons: false,
                title: {
                    type: 'inside'
                }
            },
            beforeLoad: function() {
                var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
                if (id) {
                    el = $('#' + id);
                    if (el.length) {
                        this.title = el.html();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tested the fancybox code separately, and it works, but I thought I'd leave it in to be thorough. There was also some commented out code that I took out. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the `.nav` section? Specifically wondering what the `href` values are. If there are full URLs in there (esp. something with a `/` in it), I'd expect that error, since what would `$("foo/bar.html")` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that it is this line that is causing the error:

```
var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
```

You seem to have a link with `href="/"` (a link to the start page), so the code will do the same as:

```
var item = $("/");
```

jQuery will try to parse the URL as a selector, and you get that exact error message.

Check that the `href` attribute contains a bookmark and not an URL before you try to use it as a selector:

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");
if (href.substr(0, 1) == "#") {
  var item = $(href);
  if (item.length) {
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized after I posted the question that this is the cause! You were spot on. Thanks!